# Unable to modify checked state in Kendo Treeview when setting kendoTreeViewCheckable parameters in template

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2, kendo-treeview

I'm trying to modify the example for the Kendo Treeview - Modifying the Checked State. I am VERY new to Kendo.  I've poured thru the documentation and examples and can't seem to figure out what is going on.

Here is the original one (with a modification to show if isItemChecked gets called).

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { TreeItemLookup } from '@progress/kendo-angular-treeview';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <div class="example-config">
            isItemChecked {{itemChecked}}
        </div>
        <kendo-treeview
            [nodes]="data"
            [children]="children"
            [hasChildren]="hasChildren"
            [isChecked]="isItemChecked"
            (checkedChange)="handleChecking($event)"
            textField="text"
        >
        </kendo-treeview>
        <i>Press SPACE to check/uncheck the active node</i>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
    public data: any[] = [
        {
          text: "Furniture", items: [
            { text: "Tables & Chairs" },
            { text: "Sofas" }
          ]
        },
        { text: "Decor" },
        { text: "Outdoors" }
    ];

    public children = (dataItem: any): any[] => Observable.of(dataItem.items);
    public hasChildren = (dataItem: any): boolean => !!dataItem.items;

    /* custom check implementation below */

    public checkedKeys: any[] = ["0_0"];
    public itemChecked: boolean = false;

    public isItemChecked = (_: any, index: string) => {
        this.itemChecked = true;
        return this.checkedKeys.indexOf(index) > -1 ? 'checked' : 'none';
    }

    public handleChecking(itemLookup: TreeItemLookup): void {
        this.checkedKeys = [itemLookup.item.index];
    }
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/DGVqtU3AnEJ2RzpUHW2N?p=preview

Here's the same code, except it uses [kendoTreeViewCheckable]="{ mode: 'single}".  I also noticed that public checkedKeys: any[] = ["0_0"]; is not checking the first box as it should.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { TreeItemLookup } from '@progress/kendo-angular-treeview';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <div class="example-config">
            isItemChecked {{itemChecked}}
        </div>
        <kendo-treeview
            [nodes]="data"
            [children]="children"
            [hasChildren]="hasChildren"
            [isChecked]="isItemChecked"
            (checkedChange)="handleChecking($event)"
            textField="text"
            [kendoTreeViewCheckable]="{ mode: 'single' }"
        >
        </kendo-treeview>
        <i>Press SPACE to check/uncheck the active node</i>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
    public data: any[] = [
        {
          text: "Furniture", items: [
            { text: "Tables & Chairs" },
            { text: "Sofas" }
          ]
        },
        { text: "Decor" },
        { text: "Outdoors" }
    ];

    public children = (dataItem: any): any[] => Observable.of(dataItem.items);
    public hasChildren = (dataItem: any): boolean => !!dataItem.items;

    /* custom check implementation below */

    public itemChecked: boolean = false;
    public checkedKeys: any[] = ["0_0"];

    public isItemChecked = (_: any, index: string) => {
        this.itemChecked = true;
        return this.checkedKeys.indexOf(index) > -1 ? 'checked' : 'none';
    }

    public handleChecking(itemLookup: TreeItemLookup): void {
        this.checkedKeys = [itemLookup.item.index];
    }
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/NqaqTz26AWvB0HVRIsuz?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

The TreeView component provides extensibility points that enables developer to provide a specific selection, check or expansion behavior.

For instance, the check functionality requires the `checkedChange` event and the `isChecked` callback to be configured in order to function properly. *This is exactly what [kendoTreeViewCheckable](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui-develop/components/treeview/api/CheckDirective/) directive does*. If they are overridden, like in the demo you've shared, then the **built-in implementation will be totally ignored**.

That being said, you will need to decide whether the built-in check behavior is required or not. The TreeView enables you to configure specific parts of the built-in behavior using the checkable settings:

https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui-develop/components/treeview/api/CheckableSettings/

If neither of the provided settings won't fullfill your needs, then you will need to utilize a custom check directive. You can base the custom implementation on the directive shared in the documentation:

https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui-develop/components/treeview/checkboxes/#toc-modifying-the-checked-state

Please note that it is a complete copy of the built-in one.

Comment: aha! That makes sense.  Thanks!